# MS Acces - select case mixing tables

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

I have problem with VBA code select case. Code is linked to combobox(Combo0) and event after update. In combobox there is a list of values: BHP, PPOZ, ISO. When i choose BHP, it should change source object property in subfrom(Child03) to subfrmBHP. Same with PPOZ and ISO. But for some reason, when i choose BHP it shows table from PPOZ, when i choose PPOZ it shows BHP and when i choose ISO it shows BHP. Code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
Select Case ChangeCombo
    Case Combo0 = "BHP"
   Forms("frmInstrukcje").Form.Child3.SourceObject = "subfrmBHP"
    Case Combo0 = "PPOŻ"
    Forms("frmInstrukcje").Form.Child3.SourceObject = "subfrmPPOZ"
    Case Combo0 = "ISO"
   Forms("frmInstrukcje").Form.Child3.SourceObject = "subfrmISO"
    
End Select
End Sub
```

I aleredy recreated tables, form, sub form. Someone suggested me it could be data binding in subform, but there is nothing written there.

Comment: Plelase install the free and fantastic Rubberduck add in for VBA.  Pay attention to the code inspections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method references two controls, `ChangeCombo` and `Combo0`. Not sure if it's a typo or you have something else in mind.

Anyway, `Case Combo0 = "BHP"` is incorrect, so assuming `Combo0` is the correct control, try the below.

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()
    With Forms("frmInstrukcje").Form.Child3
        Select Case Me.Combo0.Value
            Case "BHP":
               .SourceObject = "subfrmBHP"

            Case "PPOŻ":
                .SourceObject = "subfrmPPOZ"

            Case "ISO":
                .SourceObject = "subfrmISO"
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```